# How to delete Sitecore items without reference using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell-extensions, broken-links

We have multi-site application, want to delete items which are not referencing anywhere in content tree.

Following are categories:

```
1) DataSource items
2) Template
3) Media items
4) Renderings
```

How can we do using power-shell script?

We are using Sitecore 9.1.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @Michael West for nice blog post.

**Source:** https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/10010536
https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2014/10/sitecore-powershell-extensions-tip.html?_sm_au_=iVVB4RsPtStf5MfN

This is very helpful to find out and removed unused items which may be fall in any mentioned categories in above question.

Below PowerShell script is for finding media items **without** reference to any other item. Please have a look.

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Lists all media items that are not linked to other items.

    .NOTES
        Michael West
#>

# HasReference determines if the specified item is referenced by any other item.
function HasReference {
    param(
        $Item
    )

    $linkDb = [Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase
    $linkDb.GetReferrerCount($Item) -gt 0
}

<# 
    Get-MediaItemWithNoReference gets all the items in the media library
    and checks to see if they have references. Each item that does not
    have a reference is passed down the PowerShell pipeline.
#>
function Get-MediaItemWithNoReference {
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\sitecore\media library" -Recurse | 
        Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder }

    foreach($item in $items) {
        if(!(HasReference($item))) {
            $item
        }
    }
}

# Setup a hashtable to make a more readable script.
$props = @{
    InfoTitle = "Unused media items"
    InfoDescription = "Lists all media items that are not linked to other items."
    PageSize = 25
}

# Passing a hashtable to a command is called splatting. Call Show-ListView to produce
# a table with the results.
Get-MediaItemWithNoReference |
    Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
        @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
        @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} },
        @{Label="Created"; Expression={$_.__Created} },
        @{Label="Created by"; Expression={$_."__Created by"} },
        @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} }

Close-Window
```